# Trying to create nested security groups in Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create nested security groups in an active directory, with the following code:

```
DirectoryEntry newContainer = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + groupName, "group");
newContainer.Properties["description"].Value = groupId;

GrpType gt = GrpType.GlobalGrp | GrpType.SecurityGrp;
int typeNum = (int)gt;

newContainer.Properties["groupType"].Add(typeNum);
newContainer.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Add(groupName);

newContainer.CommitChanges();
```

I get no problem when creating the first level groups, but when I try to create a sub-security group inside these groups, I get a "**Naming violation**" error, with no further answer.

And by the way, I can manually create those security groups.

Comment: A group is not created 'inside' another group on a tree point of view. What do you call a sub-security group, do you want to put a group as a member of another group ?

Comment: A group is not a container - you cannot create objects "inside" a group. What you can do is have one security group be **member of** another security group - membership creates these "nested" groups - not containment.

Comment: Sorry for the terminology, I'm quite new to Active Directory handling. Precisely, I'm trying to create a sub-group that is a member of an other security group. But I'm facing a "Naming violation" for the children groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help you can find in : [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#36)

Here is an example of what you want to do whith ADSI :

```
/* Connection to Active Directory
 */
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr", "user", "password");

/* Group1 creation
 */
DirectoryEntry aGrp1 = deBase.Children.Add("cn=yourGrp1", "group");
aGrp1.Properties["description"].Value = "The description you want";
aGrp1.Properties["groupType"].Add(ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP | ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED);
aGrp1.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Add("yourGrp1");
aGrp1.CommitChanges();

/* Group2 creation
 */
DirectoryEntry aGrp2 = deBase.Children.Add("cn=yourGrp2", "group");
aGrp2.Properties["description"].Value = "The description you want";
aGrp2.Properties["groupType"].Add(ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP | ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED);
aGrp2.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Add("yourGrp2");
aGrp2.CommitChanges();

/* Group2 MemberOf Group1
 */
aGrp1.Properties["Member"].Add(aGrp2.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value);
aGrp1.CommitChanges();
```

With [Security Principals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738722%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) introduced with Framework .NET 3.5 you can do the same thing in a shortest way see : [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I will back later with it and then maybe better code